# Clear a line in the terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, shell

I sometimes start writing a command in the terminal (iTerm2) which half-way written I want to erase.

How can quickly remove all the characters on the line being worked on in the terminal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Press `Ctrl-C`. This will essentially start a new line.

To clear everything *before* the cursor position, use `Ctrl-U`.

To clear everything *after* the cursor position, use `Ctrl-K`.

These are some of the basic [Bash keyboard shortcuts](http://ss64.com/bash/syntax-keyboard.html).

Comment: Werner strikes again